# How can I append key,value pair to empty dictionary with the index value as the key pair?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, key-value

I have a list called k_points with tuples [(2.429584911990176, 0.5040720081303796), (3.396089990024489, 9.114060958885277), (5.451196187915455, 5.522005580434297)] which I want as a value in the key-value pair of this dictionary, and I want to append it, while the index will be the key pair. How can I do this?
So far, I have:

```
dict_self = {}
k_points = [(2.429584911990176, 0.5040720081303796), (3.396089990024489, 9.114060958885277), (5.451196187915455, 5.522005580434297)]

for points in k_points:
     dict_self.update({enumerate(k_points) : points})
```

and then I get the list

```
{<enumerate object at 0x0000026C7A0B36C0>: (2.429584911990176, 0.5040720081303796), <enumerate object at 0x0000026C7A0B3678>: (3.396089990024489, 9.114060958885277), <enumerate object at 0x0000026C7A0B3630>: (5.451196187915455, 5.522005580434297)}
```

which at least I get the values right but I don't get an index number as a key pair. How can I fic this probelm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean the following?

```py
d = {} 
for i in range(len(k_points)):
    d[i] = points[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go like this:

```
for i, point in enumerate(k_points):
     dict_self[i] = point
```

Or just use a dict comprehension:

```
dict_self = {i : point for i, point in enumerate(k_points)}
```

both yield:

```
 {0: (2.429584911990176, 0.5040720081303796),
 1: (3.396089990024489, 9.114060958885277),
 2: (5.451196187915455, 5.522005580434297)}
```